# How to dynamically change <NavigationCardStack/>'s direction in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, reactjs

In React Native + Redux, what would be the right approach to dynamically change the `direction` property, for transition animation, for `<NavigationCardStack/>` depending on route?

For example, when I used `<Navigator/>`, I set up `configureScene` property dynamically as such and it worked depending on different routes:

```
  configureScene(route, routeStack) {
    if(route.type === 'Modal'){
      return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom
    }
    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight
  }

<Navigator
    configureScene={this.configureScene}
    ...
/>
```

**Edit**

This is my set up -
Redux:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    navigation: state.navReducer,
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    pushRoute: (route) => push(route),
    popRoute: () => pop(),
  }
)(NavigationRoot)
```

My reducer (`navReducer.js`):

```
const initialState = {
  index: 0,
  key: 'root',
  routes: [{
   key: 'login',
   title: 'Login',
   component: Login,
   direction: 'horizontal',
  }]
}

function navigationState (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
    return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

   default:
     return state

  }
}

export default navigationState
```

And these methods handle push and pop and how navigation bar back (pop) button is set up:

```
  _handleBackAction() {
    if (this.props.navigation.index === 0) {
      return false
    }
    this.props.popRoute()
    return true
  }

  _handleNavigate(action) {
    switch (action && action.type) {
      case 'push':
        this.props.pushRoute(action.route)
        return true
      case 'back':
      case 'pop':
        return this._handleBackAction()
      default:
        return false
    }
  }

renderOverlay = (sceneProps) => {
if(0 < sceneProps.scene.index)
{
  return (
    <NavigationHeader
      {...sceneProps}
      renderLeftComponent={() => {
        switch(sceneProps.scene.route.title){
          case 'Home':
            return (
              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._handleBackAction()}>
                <Text}>X</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            )
```

And called by components like so:

```
const route = {
  home: {
    type: 'push',
    route: {
      key: 'home',
      title: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      direction: 'vertical',
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems find and you're saying it works, what's the question?

Comment: @ajmajmajma That's for `<Navigator/>` and would work different for `<NavigationCardStack/>`. For example, different parameters would have to be passed in and what should I be returning? Cause `Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom` and such wouldn't work.

Comment: @Jo Ko this not possible directly. If you look at NavigatorCardStack _renderScene method. It uses props passed to NavigatorCardStack to determine direction. Only possible way is to change direction prop depending upon active scene in your wrapping component.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationCardStack.js

Comment: @while1 Could you show an example? So I can answer the question as well.

Comment: @ajmajmajma Checking to see if you've read my previous comment. Please let me know.

Comment: @ajmajmajma Still trying to figure this out. ANy thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

ActionTypes.js

```
/*
* action types
*/
export const PUSH_ROUTE = 'PUSH_ROUTE'
export const POP_ROUTE = 'POP_ROUTE'
```

navigation.js (Navigation Action Creator)

```
import { PUSH_ROUTE, POP_ROUTE} from '../constants/ActionTypes'
export function pushRoute(route){
  return ({
    type: PUSH_ROUTE,
    route
  })
}
export function popRoute(){
  return ({
    type:POP_ROUTE
  })
}
```

navigation.js (navigation reducer)

```
import { PUSH_ROUTE, POP_ROUTE } from '../constants/ActionTypes'
import { NavigationExperimental } from 'react-native'

const {
    StateUtils: NavigationStateUtils
} = NavigationExperimental
//direction : horizontal vertical
const initialState = {
  index: 0,
  routes: [{
    key: 'tabapp',
    direction: 'horizontal'
  }]
}

function navigation(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type) {
    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      if(state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key))
        return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if(state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1)
        return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

    default:
      return state
  }
}
export default navigation
```

D8Navigator.js (Application navigation)

```
//Note:NavigationCardStack dirction 


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    NavigationExperimental,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { pushRoute, popRoute } from './actions/navigation'
import D8TabsView from './tabs/D8TabsView'
import LoginView from './tabs/user/LoginView'

const {
  CardStack: NavigationCardStack
} = NavigationExperimental

class D8Navigator extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this._onPopRoute = this._onPopRoute.bind(this)
    this._renderScene = this._renderScene.bind(this)
  }
  _onPopRoute(){
    this.props.dispatch(popRoute())
  }
  _renderScene(sceneProps){
    const {route} = sceneProps.scene
    switch(route.key){
      case "tabapp":
      return (
        <D8TabsView />
      )
      case "loginview":
        return (
          <LoginView />
        )
      default:
        return
    }
  }
  render(){
    let { navigationState } = this.props
    return (
      <NavigationCardStack
        direction={navigationState.routes[navigationState.index].direction}
        navigationState={this.props.navigationState}
        onNavigateBack={this._onPopRoute}
        renderScene={this._renderScene} />
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    navigationState: state.navigation
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(D8Navigator)
```

D8TabsView.ios.js

```
...
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { pushRoute, popRoute } from '../actions/navigation'
...
render(){
        return (
            <TabBarIOS
        tintColor="#f33"
        barTintColor="#fff"
        unselectedTintColor="#888">
                .....

        <Icon.TabBarItemIOS
          title="My"
          iconName="ios-person-outline"
          selectedIconName="ios-person"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'starred'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.dispatch(pushRoute({
              key:'loginview', direction:'vertical'
            }))
          }}>
        </Icon.TabBarItemIOS>
            </TabBarIOS>
        )
    }
```

"My" tabBarItem onPress dispatch loginview scene with 'vertical'.

LoginView.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { popRoute } from '../../actions/navigation'

class LoginView extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Login</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight
          underlayColor="#D0D0D0"
          onPress={()=>this.props.dispatch(popRoute())}>
          <Text>
            Close
          </Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default connect()(LoginView)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works beautifully. One more question before I accept the answer, for `popRoute()`, how can I pop with the same direction? For example, if the `push` with the direction `vertical` is made, when it is popped, how can I make it so that it does in a `vertical` direction as well? Thank you!

Comment: if the push with the direction "vertical" is made, when popped, a "vertical" direction is automatic.  Because pushing with the direction "vertical",  the NavigationCardStack's  direction is set "vertical" ,  when popped,  it does in a "vertical" direction as well.

Comment: That's extremely weird then, because even if it gets pushed `vertical`, when `popped` it is done so horizontally. Could it be that I am missing something? I updated the original post with code. Please take a look.

Comment: if you've seen my last comment, please let me know. thank you!

Comment: Do you mind showing with the code that I provided? Everything seem to look the same yet doesn't work -- even though pushed: 'vertical' it still pops horizontally.

Comment: Just checking in to see if you've read my previous comment. Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

When your navigation card refer to route object and navigation pop action occur,
your navigation card lost the reference as the pop action removes the route object.

So i recommend the method written on the bottom.

/constants/ActionTypes.js

```
// navigation action types
export const NAV_PUSH_ROUTE = 'NAV_PUSH_ROUTE';
export const NAV_POP_ROUTE = 'NAV_POP_ROUTE';

// tab action types
export const TAB_SELECT = 'TAB_SELECT';
```

/actions/navigationActions.js

```
/**
 * Navigation Actions
 * @flow
 */

import { NAV_POP_ROUTE, NAV_PUSH_ROUTE } from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const navPush = route => {
  const rtRoute = route;
  if (route && route.direction === undefined) rtRoute.direction = 'horizontal';

  return {
    type: NAV_PUSH_ROUTE,
    route: rtRoute,
  };
};

const navPop = () => (
  {
    type: NAV_POP_ROUTE,
  }
);

module.exports = {
  navPush,
  navPop,
};
```

/reducer/navigationReducer.js

```
/**
 * Navigation reducer
 * @flow
 */

import { NavigationExperimental } from 'react-native';

import { NAV_POP_ROUTE, NAV_PUSH_ROUTE } from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const {
  StateUtils: NavigationStateUtils,
} = NavigationExperimental;

const initialState = {
  index: 0,
  key: 'global',
  routes: [
    {
      key: 'feed',
      title: 'Feed',
    },
  ],
};

const navigationState = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NAV_PUSH_ROUTE:
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) {
        return state;
      }

      const navigationNewState = NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route);
      return {
        ...navigationNewState,
        direction: action.route.direction,
      };

    case NAV_POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) {
        return state;
      }
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state);

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

module.exports = navigationState;
```

/components/global/ECNavigator.js

```
/**
 * Everychoose navigation compoment for example
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  NavigationExperimental,
  BackAndroid,
  TouchableHighlight,
  PixelRatio,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { navPush, navPop } from '../../../actions';

import LoginScreen from '../../views/LoginScreen';

const {
  CardStack: NavigationCardStack,
} = NavigationExperimental;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  row: {
    padding: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#30b3d8',
    borderBottomWidth: 1 / PixelRatio.get(),
    borderBottomColor: '#CDCDCD',
  },
  rowText: {
    fontSize: 17,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
});

const routes = {
  loginScreenV: {
    type: 'push',
    route: {
      key: 'LoginScreen',
      title: 'Login screen vertical',
      direction: 'vertical',
    },
  },
  loginScreenH: {
    type: 'push',
    route: {
      key: 'LoginScreen',
      title: 'Login screen horizontal',
    },
  },
};

class ECNavigator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._renderScene = this._renderScene.bind(this);
    this._handleBackAction = this._handleBackAction.bind(this);
    this._handleNavigate = this._handleNavigate.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._handleBackAction);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._handleBackAction);
  }

  _handleBackAction() {
    if (this.props.navigation.index === 0) {
      return false;
    }

    this.props.popRoute();
    return true;
  }

  _handleNavigate(action) {
    switch (action && action.type) {
      case 'push':
        this.props.pushRoute(action.route);
        return true;

      case 'back':
      case 'pop':
        return this._handleBackAction();

      default:
        return false;
    }
  }

  _renderScene(props) {
    const { route } = props.scene;

    switch (route.key) {
      case 'LoginScreen':
        return <LoginScreen navGoBack={this._handleBackAction} />;
      default:
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={styles.row}
              underlayColor="#d0d0d0"
              onPress={() => this._handleNavigate(routes.loginScreenV)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                Go to LoginScreen (Vertical)
              </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={styles.row}
              underlayColor="#d0d0d0"
              onPress={() => this._handleNavigate(routes.loginScreenH)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                Go to LoginScreen (Horizontal)
              </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return (
      <NavigationCardStack
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        direction={navigation.direction}
        onNavigateBack={this._handleBackAction}
        navigationState={this.props.navigation}
        onNavigate={this._handleNavigate}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
      />
    );
  }
}

ECNavigator.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object,
  pushRoute: PropTypes.func,
  popRoute: PropTypes.func,
};

const select = store => ({
  navigation: store.navigation,
});

const actions = dispatch => ({
  pushRoute: route => dispatch(navPush(route)),
  popRoute: () => dispatch(navPop()),
});

module.exports = connect(select, actions)(ECNavigator);
```

/components/view/LoginScreen.js

```
/**
 * LoginScreen compoment
 * @flow
 */

import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  TouchableHighlight,
  PixelRatio,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { navPush, navPop } from '../../../actions';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  row: {
    padding: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#30b3d8',
    borderBottomWidth: 1 / PixelRatio.get(),
    borderBottomColor: '#CDCDCD',
  },
  rowText: {
    fontSize: 17,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
});

const LoginScreen = props => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Login Screen</Text>
    <TouchableHighlight
      style={styles.row}
      underlayColor="#d0d0d0"
      onPress={props.navGoBack}
    >
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
        Go back
      </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
);

module.exports = LoginScreen;
```

[Result screen - GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzRbh.gif)